# Как перемешать строки в текстовом файле

Tags: php

Есть slovar.txt с множеством слов, каждое начинается с новой строки:

```
СЛОВО
СЛОВО
СЛОВО
```

Как можно перемешать эти строки если их там 41470

Comment: загрузить файл целиком в массив, перемешать и записать обратно. Современные объемы оперативной памяти это позволяют (если у вас конечно "слова" длиной не по десятку килобайт)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант:

```
$a = file('1.txt');
shuffle($a);
file_put_contents('2.txt', implode('', $a));
```

Comment: `implode("\n", ..)`

Comment: @teran Это не требуется, поскольку каждый элемент массива уже содержит перевод строки.

Comment: а, да. тупанул.

Comment: Передача массива в `file_put_contents` аналогична `implode('', $a)`. Так что можно сократить до `file_put_contents('2.txt', $a);`